# Make a Image glow with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make Images glow while hovering above them with your mouse with jquery. I have tried multiple ways but none worked..

The images that are supposed to glow are the ones in the list. I have to use Jquery since thats the Exercize I got from school...

And yes, I may use Stackoverflow :p

HTML:

```
    <h1>Grand Theft Auto V - Showcase</h1>
</header>
<div id="contentHolder">
        <div id="three-columns" class="grid-container">
            <ul class="rig columns-3">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/1.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/2.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/3.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/4.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/5.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/6.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/7.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/8.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/9.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/10.jpg" />
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(".rig img").hover(function(){
    $("this").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 5px #ddd");
    }, function(){
    $("this").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 5px #ddd");
});
```

Comment: Should be: `$(this)` (no quotes)

Comment: when do you want them to glow? on click? all the time? on hover?

Comment: The images should glow on hover

Comment: Why not just make a CSS class to apply when you hover? Define the CSS class (example "glow")... In that class define the box-shadow you want. Then use jQuery to apply that class (`addClass`) on hover, and remove it (`removeClass`) on mouse out....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your javascript, you have something like:

```
$("this").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 5px #ddd");
```

Because you've wrapped `"this"` in quotes jquery interprets that as a string and tries to find a `<this></this>` element. What you want to do, is:

```
$(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 5px #ddd");
```

No quotes. In jquery, `$(this)` refers to the element in the current context. For hover, its the element currently being hovered over.

Comment: Changed it, Still doesn't work...? Do I need to put the box-shadow in the css aswell?

Comment: Its possible the `box-shadow` is being applied but you don't notice it because `#ddd` is very close in color to white. Try changing `#ddd` to `#f00`. Once you confirm it works you can play with the color.

Comment: How are you including your javascript? If its in the head, you need to wrap it like this: `$(function(){ /* Your code here */ })`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe...

JS:

```
$('.holder').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.effect').addClass('glow');
    }, function(){
     $(this).find('.effect').removeClass('glow');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class='effect'></div>
   <img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.glow {
     box-shadow:0px 0px 50px 30px #dedede inset;    
}
body {
    background:black;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
.effect {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.holder {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
```

I made little complicated html structure, because i think that inset glow works better, so, .effect div covers image... looks good, imho. :)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/L9dypg7f/